# Weighting Problem

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have a question with weighting my character.

[image]
This is how it is without actually applying subdivison modifier. Very low poly but the problem is :
[image]
Its very hard to paitn weight in weight mode ( cant get rid of green & yellow area without actually touching the red area ).

So what I did was :
[image]

applied the subdivision to the object.
It did get much much easier to paint weight as there are more faces now, but the problem is there are way too many faces as you can see  :PPP [image]

Would there be a simpler way of weighting without adding that much of faces to the object?

Thanks!

Comment: you can subdivide once only, it won't give such a dense topology

Comment: I think that was my first subdivision applied to the object

Comment: If you've used a Subdivision Surface modifier, what was the ratio? I doubt it was 1 judging by the mesh density. I hope you've kept a low-poly version, keep a copy somewhere, now give it a new modifier or simply right click > Subdivide and in the Operator box (bottom left of your 3D view) choose a Number of Cuts of 1. Also, for all the joints parts (like elbows, knees...) you'll have to add edge loops so that it bends nicely

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I went back to what it is in the first picture in this post, removed subdivision modifier. When I subdivide with right clicking on edit mode, set cut and click back onto the screen, nothing happens.
Sorry I am new to blender, i might be missing something super basic

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: On the modifier corner, would setting the number of "Levels Viewport low" (e.g 1)  and setting "Render" number high (6) be a way and cause no trouble rigging with the "edge loops" you wrote?

Comment: okay again thanks for helping

Comment: if you use a Subsurf modifier, use a subdivision level of 1, if you use right click > Subdivide, go in the Operator box and choose a Number of Cuts of 1